# Android 5.0 - Implement the Google Play Movies Material design "My movies" screen

Tags: android, header, parallax, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I'd like to implement that screen from the new GPlay Movies material version :

[image]

If you haven't tried the app yet, the best way to see what I mean is to check it [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/18/google-play-movies-tv-shows-3-4-23-android-tv-adds-material-design-ui-live-actor-information-cards-for-chromecast-users-apk-download/).

So I have a `RecyclerView` coupled with a `GridLayoutManager` for the grid. And I thought about adding a header view with a red background to the grid. Note that I'd also like to add the same parallax effect on this header view than on the Movies app.

For now, I don't really need the support of the tabs (I want to make it work with a `RecyclerView`, not a `ViewPager`).

I used to make this kind of screen work with a solution based on this tuto [this tuto](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) by Cyrill Mottier and the source code of [this lib](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar/) by Flavien Laurent. But these solutions worked for `ListViews` or `ScrollViews`, but are not (yet) adapted to the `RecyclerView`.

Would you have some idea on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance,

VieuMa

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a bit going on when scrolling in in the My Movies screen (or in the Google Play Music app). Here's how thing basically work:

### General Idea

1. Create a simple colored view with your actionbar color behind your `RecylcerView`
2. Add your tabs (or dummy tab, in your case) to the `Toolbar` container view.
3. Add an `OnScrollListener` to your `RecyclerView` (the more difficult part).  Use the `dy` (delta in y-direction) to
   parallax-scroll your colored view. If *scrolling down*, translate
   the toolbar container towards the top of the screen.  If *scolling
   up*, show the toolbar container (unless it's already visible)

### Code

In your **activity.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Actual content (could also be in a fragment -->
    <View
    android:id="@+id/coloredView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="#CC0000" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="120dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />

    <!-- Toolbar (container)  -->
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#CC0000"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        style="@style/Toolbar" />

    <!-- Fake tab ;) -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Dummy tab"
        android:background="#CC0000"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

In *onCreate()* of your **MainActivity.java**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init your recyclerview here.

    final View toolbarContainer = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_container);
    final View coloredView = findViewById(R.id.coloredView);

    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy < 0) {
                onScrollUp(dy);
            } else {
                onScrollDown(dy);
            }
        }

        private void onScrollDown(int dy) {
            coloredView.setTranslationY(coloredView.getTranslationY() - dy / 3);
            toolbarContainer.setTranslationY(toolbarContainer.getTranslationY() - dy);
        }

        private void onScrollUp(int dy) {
            coloredView.setTranslationY(coloredView.getTranslationY() - dy / 3);

            if (toolbarContainer.getTranslationY() < 0) {
                showToolbar();
            }
        }

        private void showToolbar() {
            toolbarContainer.animate()
                    .translationY(0)
                    .setDuration(200)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .start();
        }

    });
```

### Result

[image]

(I've left out little details like the toolbar shadow or the toolbar showing its full height if it wasn't fully hidden.)

Hope that helps!

PS: The title of your question is very specific. Maybe you should change it to something like "Hiding toolbar on recyclerview scroll like in Google Play/Play Music" so that this thread is easier to find ;)